# Codeigniter: Store and Load Style in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

So, I'm just playing around with Codeigniter.

I've made 5 square, static. 
I have declared those 5 square positions.
But when I delete one of those square (For example: Square 1/ #draggable1), the other square are being sorted.

> This is the condition:
>
> I Have 5 Square/ 5 #draggable
>
> Sq1   Sq2   Sq3   Sq4   Sq5
>
> When I delete Sq2, this is what happen:
>
> Sq1   Sq3   Sq4   Sq5
>
> Then I delete Sq4, this is what happen:
>
> Sq1   Sq3   Sq5
>   All the square being sorted when I delete one of them. All I want to do is when I delete one of those square, the other square doesn't need to sorted. Just the they were. Like this:
>
> Sq1   Sq2   Sq3   Sq4   Sq5
>
> When I delete Sq2, it should be like this:
>
> Sq1   ___   Sq3   Sq4   Sq5     *no Sq2 and there is space between Sq1 and Sq3

This is my **View**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("style/css/bootstrap.min.css"); ?>">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style type='text/css'>
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        a {
            color: blue;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>


    <style>
        #draggable1 { width: 90px; height: 90px; left:56px; top:35px; opacity:0; }
        #draggable2 { width: 90px; height: 90px; left:170px; top:-55px; opacity:0; }
        #draggable3 { width: 90px; height: 90px; left:285px; top:-145px; opacity:0; }
        #draggable4 { width: 90px; height: 90px; left:398px; top:-235px; opacity:0; }
        #draggable5 { width: 90px; height: 90px; left:512px; top:-325px; opacity:0; }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable1" ).draggable().delay(100).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
            $( "#draggable2" ).draggable().delay(200).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
            $( "#draggable3" ).draggable().delay(300).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
            $( "#draggable4" ).draggable().delay(400).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
            $( "#draggable5" ).draggable().delay(500).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
         if(is_array($databuku)){

             echo '<ol><br>';
             $i = 1;
             foreach($databuku as $key){
                 $judul = '<div id="draggable'.$i++.'" class="ui-widget-content"><center><strong>'.$key->tbl_name.'</strong>
                                 <br> <br>
                                 <a href="hall_a.html">' .$key->index_no. ' / ' .$key->id. '</a>
                                 <br>

                                 '.anchor('perpustakaan/koreksi_buku/'.$key->id, 'Edit').' |
                                 '.anchor('perpustakaan/konfirm_hapus_buku/'.$key->id, 'Delete').'

                                 </center></div>';
                     echo $judul;
                }
                echo '</ol>';
            }

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Now I'm thinking that the easiest way is to store and load the left and top position from CSS in database.
The Question is:
How store and load **left** and **top** in the style CSS to/from Database?
For example:
I have **left**:512px; **top**:-325px; in my Table Database,
How to load those amount of left and top in my body code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want the style to be read from the DB, but here is how:

You should see the [CodeIngiter Documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/docs) first.

You create a model that loads your data (e.g.: my_model.php):

```
public function getSize(){

  //get the style from the DB
  $this->db->where('style', '10');

  return $this->db->get('my_table')->row();

}
```

You load your model in the controller:

```
public function controllerOne(){

  //get the model loaded
  $this->load->model('my_model');

  //Set your data from the model
  $data = array(

    'mySize' => $this->my_model->getSize();

  );

  //Load the view with the data
  $this->load->view('my_view', $data);

}
```

You will now have a variable called `mySize`in your view that you can read:

```
print_r($mySize);
```

Just as a note, I would use a faster an quicker way to load dynamic sizes, which is to get into the `application > config > config.php` and add new configuration options:

```
$config['size_left'] = "321px";
$config['size_right'] = "134px";
```

And then read them in the controller or view by:

```
$this->config->item('size_left');
```

Comment: Hi, what if I want to add new configuration in config.php about opacity? Am I right about this code? $config['opacity'] = "0";  And then I read it in the controller this way $this->config->item('opacity');

Comment: @yogieputra yes, sure.